# How can you test that an element does not exist with PHPUnit/Selenium?

Tags: php, testing, selenium, phpunit

I'm new to PHPUnit and Selenium, and I want to test a 'remove' button by confirming that an element with a given ID exists before the button is clicked, but no longer exists after the button is clicked.

If I use something like this to check that the element has been deleted:

```
$this->assertFalse($this->byId('idRemoved'));
```

Then I get a test failure in `byId()` because it can't find `idRemoved` (which is true, because it's not there.)

How can I test for the lack of an element, so the test fails if `idRemoved` is found?

Comment: Do you want to check whether the `remove` button is present or not before performing the click operation? Am i right?

Comment: No, the remove button deletes an element from the page (e.g. a table row.)  So I want to make sure the remove button is doing its job and this other element has been deleted, after the button has been clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java equivalent will be

```
   public boolean isElementExists(By by) {
        boolean isExists = true;
        try {
            driver.findElement(by);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            isExists = false;
        }
        return isExists;
    }
```

Comment: @vasanth because I am not familiar with php and wanted to convey solution. OP was able to get the idea out of it and found answer. Check OPs answer below. Did it caused any harm?

Comment: phpselenium has different APIs..drawing parallels would lead to searching for a solution in a different direction. That was my only humble understanding.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I ended up using, thanks to Karna's suggestion.  I'm posting it as another answer as I am using PHP, so for the benefit of anyone else using PHPUnit and Selenium, here is a similar method to Karna's, but for PHPUnit:

```
try {
    $this->byId('idRemoved');
    $this->fail('The element was not deleted.');
} catch (PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException $e) {
    $this->assertEquals(PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException::NoSuchElement, $e->getCode());
}
```

The code was taken from [line 1070 in the PHPUnit Selenium test code](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/Tests/Selenium2TestCaseTest.php#L1070), which I found after Karna pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

For those arriving late at the party: a better solution would be to create your own expected condition class and extend the `Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverExpectedCondition` to write your own method:

```
public function elementNotPresent(WebDriverBy $by)
{
    return new static(
        function (WebDriver $driver) use ($by) {
            try {
                $driver->findElement($by);
                return false;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    );
}
```

**Update:** The above is intended for Facebook's Selenium [WebDriver bindings for PHP](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/)

Comment: +1, but note this works for https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/ , not when using the old Selenium2TestCase from https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You can assert that a specific exception gets thrown if you'd like:

```
/**
 * @expectedException        MyException
 * @expectedExceptionMessage Some Message
 */
public function testExceptionHasRightMessage()
{
    //yourCodeThatThrows new MyException('Some Message')
}
```

Comment: This could work for cases where the test on its own is looking for the lack of an element.  However in my case the lack of an element is just an additional "safety" check within a larger test, so I don't want the test aborted when the exception is thrown, it should only abort if the exception is not thrown.  But thanks for the suggestion!